# How to maintain previous changed state in REACT JS as when new item is updated, previous is set to default?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping, state, shopping-cart

I have a **shopping Cart in react** (***Not using Redux***) which has Quantity input field infront of each item. **Qty** is 1 by default for all. **TotalPrice** for each item is infornt of it(unitPrice*1). Now if user updates Qty value, TotalPrice needs to be **updated**(unitPrice*Qty). My code is doing it but **issue** is when i update one item Qty, it updates Price, great, but when I update another item Qty, **previously updated Price gets reset to default** (back to UnitPrice).

I searched it alot but no use. Most People use redux but I dont want to use it. So please help me if u see a solution to it **as I want to maintain all the updated prices.**

```js
export default class Cart extends Component
{
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        data:[],
        customer: '',
        redirectToReferrer: false,
        cart: [],
        cartItems: [],
        
        qty: '',
        clicked: ''      };
 this.onChangeQty = this.onChangeQty.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
 
    const retrieved = localStorage.getItem("cartItem");
    const arr = JSON.parse(retrieved);
    axios.post('http://localhost/Auth/api/customers/show_cart.php', arr,
     {
    headers: {'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    } )
    .then(response => {
    this.setState({
             cartItems :response.data.records
           });
      })
     .catch(error => {
     if (error) {
       console.log("Error");  }
       });

}


onChangeQty(sid,e)
{
this.setState({
  clicked: sid,
  qty: e.target.value })

}

  render()
  {
    return (
<div id="profileDiv">

<Col md="12" lg="12" sm="12" xs="12">
<h1> <b> Your Shopping Cart </b>  </h1>

<Table>
<thead>
    <tr className="text-center">

        <th> Item# </th>
        <th> Image </th>
        <th> ID</th>
        <th> Name</th>
        <th> Unit Price </th>
        <th> Quantity </th>
        <th> Total Price </th>

    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
{this.state.cartItems.map( (item, i) =>

  <tr>

    <td className="text-center">
      <h4 key={i}> {i}</h4>
    </td>

    <td className="text-center">
    <Image src={"data:image/png[jpg];base64," +  item.Image}
     id="cartImage" alt="abc" />
    </td>

    <td className="text-center">
      <h4>{item.SparePartID}</h4>
    </td>

    <td className="text-center">
      <h4> {item.Name}</h4>
    </td>

    <td className="text-center">
      <h4 >{item.Price} </h4>
    </td>

    <td className="text-center">
      <h4 key={item.SparePartID}>
      <input className="text-center"
       type="number"
      min="1"
      onChange={(e) => this.onChangeQty(item.SparePartID, e)}
      />
      </h4>
    </td>

    <td className="text-center">
      <h4 key={item.SparePartID}>
      {
         this.state.clicked == item.SparePartID ?
         (item.Price*this.state.qty) : item.Price     
      }
      </h4>
    </td>

  </tr>

)}  </tbody>
</Table>
</Col>
</div>  ); }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is, when you get your cart items, to go through each item and to add a quantity for each of them. And add a total in state for the total of all products.

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        data:[],
        customer: '',
        redirectToReferrer: false,
        cart: [],
        cartItems: [],
        totalPrice: 0
        clicked: ''      };
 this.onChangeQty = this.onChangeQty.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {

    const retrieved = localStorage.getItem("cartItem");
    const arr = JSON.parse(retrieved);
    axios.post('http://localhost/Auth/api/customers/show_cart.php', arr,
     {
    headers: {'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    } )
    .then(response => {
    let myItems = [];
    response.forEach(item => {
      myItems.push({id: item.id, name: item.name, qty: 1, price: item.price, total: item.price});
    })
    this.setState({
             cartItems :myItems
           });
      })
     .catch(error => {
     if (error) {
       console.log("Error");  }
       });

}
```

OnChange method should find the selected product and update its quantity, and the totalPrice:

```
onChangeQty(sid,e)
{
  const items = this.state.cartItems;
  const item = items.find(item => item.id === sid);
  const index = items.indexOf(item);
  item.qty = e.target.value;
  item.total = item.qty * item.price;
  items[index] = index;

  let totalPrice = 0;
  items.forEach(item => {
      totalPrice += item.qty * item.price;
  });

  this.setState({
    cartItems: items,
    totalPrice
  });

}
```

and in html you can show the total price as

```
{this.state.totalPrice}
```

and if you want total of each item you can simply check it by

```
this.state.cartItems.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item.total);
})
```

Comment: Thanks alot for response. I think u meant in htm I can show by {this.state.totalPrice},  tried same as u told but it's now updating price for all the products eventhough Im updating qty for one specific product.

Comment: @YellowMinion yes sorry, i typed it wrong in onchange method, in the setState I typed it total instead of totalPrice. I updated the code and check again if you can. Then let me know if it does work

Comment: Yes I got it that it was a typo so I had already updated "total" to "totalPrice". But it's updating TotalPrice against all products instead of that specific one.  I think its setting same state of totalPrice for all.

Comment: @YellowMinion check it now. I've added total to each product when you first get from axios. And then update total of each item on onChage event, and then in the end its shown how you can get it

Comment: Sorry for bothering again. I did same and It shows Error on this line **const item = item.items.find(item => item.id === sid);**  Error saying that _typeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined_

Comment: @YellowMinion sorry my bad, that should be `items.find()...` not `item.items.find()...`.

Comment: Thanks alot. It worked. I really appreciate your response and help. God bless u.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same state for different for every item, so every changes you do to quantity will modify your state and so the item price of everything. there is no need to use redux for this. You can do two things: move the item logic to a sub component, so , every item will have his own state, or, modify you state to handle an array of objects like `{name:'itemname', price:itemPrice etc etc}` this way you'll edit only a specific item or improve your cartItems: [] with the qty prop.

EDIT:

now you can try to render n sub components that i've called ChartItem, they will receive `{...item}` the you can . use from inside your component via `this.props.yourItemProp`

```
{this.state.cartItems.map( (item, i) => <ChartItem key={i} {...item} />}
```

Now, in every ChartItem you can define a private state and use it. If you want to comunicate to the parent component just pass to the child compone t a function like

```
  {this.state.cartItems.map( (item, i) => <ChartItem key={i} {...item}
onItemSomething={this.handleOnItemSomething}
```

/>}

so, you can call this.props.onItemSomething to comunicate with your parent component

Comment: Thanks alot for response. I have updated my cartItems[ ] and now each item has a qty=1 with it. Now would you please elaborate how to move my logic to sub-Component? Should I pass a ID and qty prop in Sub-Component where It'd calculate totalPrice according to updated Qty? I would be v thankful for some help.

Comment: @YellowMinion edited mu ansewer, hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the way you are managing your cartItems. In onChangeQty you should iterate over your this.state.cartItems and find the item with the selected sid , you could use

```
onChangeQty (sid, {target:{value}}){

    let {cartItems } = this.state
    let ind = cartItems.findIndex( o => o.sid === sid) //get index and 
                                                       //update the 
                                                       // qty of 
                                                       // that element of the cartItems 
                                                       // array , 
     cartItems[ind].sid + = value

    this.setState({cartItems})
}
```